# Subsonic 3 - how do you execute a stored procedure that returns a value?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

How do you execute a stored procedure in subsonic 3.0 that returns a value? For example many of my stored procedures return @@identity, and I can't figure out how to access that value without re querying the table. Again, not an output parameter, but a return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StoredProcedure sproc = db.FancySchmancySproc();
sproc.Execute();
int output = (int)sproc.Output; // returns type 'object' so you'll need to cast
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StoredProcedure sp = SPs.TestProcedure(0);

sp.Command.AddReturnParameter();

object retValue = sp.Command.Parameters.Find(delegate(QueryParameter p)
{ 
  return p.Mode == ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; 
}).ParameterValue;

if (retValue!=null)
{

  // cast the value to the type expected

  int rc = (int) retValue;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
StoredProcedure sproc = db.FancySchmancySproc();
sproc.ExecuteScalar<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok ... I had it working with what John Sheehan said, suddenly it just started giving me an exception.

I'm just testing with the following SP.

---

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE TestLocal

@a numeric(18,0)
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

return 10

END

GO

---

and my code in C# is the following

---

StoredProcedure sp = new DB().TestLocal(1);

sp.Execute();

int timeLeft = (int)sp.Output;

return timeLeft;

---

Edit 1:

I got it working by doing the following but I don't think that's the right way to do it.

---

StoredProcedure sp = new DB().TestLocal(1);

sp.Command.AddReturnParameter();

sp.Execute();

int myReturnValue = (int)sp.Command.OutputValues[0];

return myReturnValue;

Answer (score 1):

I've been running stored procs using ActiveRecord like so;

```
// Connect to DB and run the stored proc into a dataset
myDatabasedb db = new myDatabasedb();
DataSet ds = db.myStoredProc(firstparam, secondparam, etc);

// Now you can do what you like with the dataset!
Gridview1.datasource = ds.executeDataSet();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what I thought, but  sproc.output is always null. I wonder if there's a bug in the latest version 3.0.0.3

Answer (score 0):

```
StoredProcedure sproc = db.FancySchmancySproc();
sproc.ExecuteDataSet();
```